# Como chamar um evento com base em um elemento que foi criado dinamicamente depois que o DOM foi carregado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Eu tenho um script que adiciona elementos dinamicamente e preciso chamar um evento ao clicar na classe.

**Fluxo**:

1. Ao clicar no botão "Adicionar", dispara o evento "adicionar.onclick" que cria inputs dinamicamente.
2. Cada novo input que foi criado tem uma classe "btn-excluir".
3. Ao clicar na classe "btn-excluir" deverá disparar o evento
   "excluir.onclick" e é exatamente nessa parte aqui que não estou
   conseguindo fazer, porque a classe "btn-excluir" foi criada depois
   que o DOM foi carregado.

**Eu já consegui o resultado esperado usando JQuery:**

```
/*Essa função funciona e eu quero fazer exatamente isso com JavaScript puro*/
$(document).on('click','.btn-excluir',function(){

   //meu código
})
```

**Porém agora eu preciso fazer usando Javascript puro. Esse é todo meu código:**

```html
<main class="container pt-5">
        <form>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">CADASTRAR PROFISSIÃO</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" id="btn-adicionar">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Adicionar
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-salvar">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i> Salvar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
```

```
let cont = 0;
let tag;

const card      = document.querySelector('.card-body');
const adicionar = document.querySelector('#btn-adicionar');
let excluir   = document.getElementsByClassName('.btn-excluir');

/*Esse evento está OK*/
adicionar.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addInput();
}

/*Esse evento que estou com problemas*/
excluir.onclick = function(){
    console.log('deletado')
}

function addInput(){
    cont += 1;
    tag =  '';
    tag += '<div class="input-group mb-2 grupo">';
    tag += '<label for="nome'+cont+'" class="pt-2 pr-2">Nome:</label>';
    tag += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome'+cont+'">';
    tag += '<div class="input-group-append">';
    tag += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-excluir" type="button">';
    tag += '<i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>';
    tag += '</button>';
    tag += '</div>';
    tag += '</div>';
    card.innerHTML = tag;
}
```

Comment: Se a reposta era a que você esperava, me ajudaria se você a marcasse como resposta correta.

Answer (score -1):

A função do listener pode se referir ao evento (o que você já fez no listener no adicionar), e inclusive ao elemento clicado com a propriedade `target`.

Portanto, creio que funciona para você colocar o listener no `document` e testar a classe do elemento clicado:

```
document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const elementoClicado = event.target
    if (!elementoClicado.classList.contains("btn-excluir")) return
    //Meu código
    event.preventDefault
    alert("Aqui você coloca o que quer fazer quando alguém clicar")
})
```